# Should I commit ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/?

Tags: ios, git, flutter

After running my new Flutter app for a first time on iOS, `git status` is reporting untracked files

```
ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
```

Should I add this to version control or add them to `.gitignore`?

Comment: If you shouldn't it were listed in `.gitignore`. It also doesn't seem to contain machine or user-dependent information.

Answer (score 3):

The `xcshareddata` folder does not contain any user sensitive data, or even machine sensitive data.

That directory, as the name implies, is used to store shared settings, e.g: Schemes. In my experience, it is best to add it to version control, as there seems to be no good reason to keep it from being versioned.